# Mount volume using Docker API

Tags: docker

I have a Docker host that is controlled using Docker API, like [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.27/).

I can create a new volume and a new container using this API very easily.

But how can I create new container and mount this volume to this container, using only API?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can mount the previously created volume (let's say `volume1`) to the container using the `HostConfig` in the create request. In the `HostConfig` you can specify the mounts (`Mounts`) you want to create.

A `Mount` would be like:

```
{
   "Target":   "path/in/the/container",
   "Source":   "volumeName",
   "Type":     "volume", 
   "ReadOnly": false
}
```

So the informations you should add to the create request is the next:

```
"HostConfig": {
    "Mounts": [
        {
           "Target":   "path/in/the/container",
           "Source":   "volume1",
           "Type":     "volume", 
           "ReadOnly": false
        }
     ]
}
```

I also recommend you to dig into this documentation from Docker. You can find a lot of good and useful information there.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.27/#operation/ContainerCreate